# Is TestRPC reporting TO wrong on transactions?

Tags: ethereum, truffle

```
{ hash: '0xcc871efa64631ff57b6c4cdf9e9c52dce299956cc0bc2cdf6781dbd647a80926',
  nonce: 34,
  blockHash: '0xf4e21dabc0d6f99ae9a3fd128b9f25462110ed0e2811c0d5f91ffce9ac85594a',
  blockNumber: 49,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  from: '0x9c3fe8bc6d259d44e80fb728e74727bfbe58e988',
  to: '0xb22ab8533936d6d75c1ecf229c1ad68410ea8ee3',
  value: { [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] },
  gas: 3141592,
  gasPrice: { [String: '1'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 1 ] },
  input: '0x1f5c1d9800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000007fa543843e2f5766ad623b2155d639d73635824400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000134f70656e20412042616e6b204163636f756e7400000000000000000000000000’ }
```

I am getting a transaction back from a x.send(1) whose JSON looks like the above.  I can see in the value of the *input* attribute that there was a “7fa543843e2f5766ad623b2155d639d736358244” that matches the address of the account I provided for x. The Solidity snippet is:

```
function do(string _description, address x) {
   if ( msg.sender != owner )
       throw;
   description = _description;

    x.send(1);
 }
```

However, the to: attribute in the JSON is wrong.  My environment is using tests run in Truffle against TestRPC. Does anyone recognize this as a known issue or a problem on my part?

The appropriate part of my test code is:

```
 .then(
    function (_bool0) {
        assert.isTrue(_bool0,"whoops");
        return contract.do("a test", accounts[4], {from: accounts[0]} );
    }).then(
    function (tx_id) {
        var transaction = web3.eth.getTransaction(tx_id);
        /* debugging my test */
        console.log(transaction);

        assert.strictEqual(transaction.to,accounts[4],"transaction \"to:\" was not provided address");

        done();
    }
).catch(done);
```

Comment: I think this is an issue to do with the tx_id being related to the contract and not the x.send() I had done. I needed the transaction id of the send().

Comment: if you feel your questions do not recieve enough attention on stackoverflow, you can also try asking ethereum-specific questions on the new [ethereum stack exchange beta site](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour was actually consistent with how Ethereum works. When the test calls:

```
contract.do("a test", accounts[4], {from: accounts[0]} );
```

it causes a transaction that is recorded on the blockchain. A transaction FROM the accounts[0] account and to the Contract: which is also a type of account. The object returned to my test represents this transaction: shown as the JSON above.

I had mistakenly thought the returned object represented the transaction between the Contract to the second account.

To achieve my test objective I need to check for the existence of a transaction from the second account. I'll update this once I have figured it out.